# Using .each() with IF statement

Tags: jquery

I want to take the value of .day, if statement, and add class to .count with that value.
This html is one of the slides. There are several slides.

it doesn't work.
how can i fix it?

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.new-container article').each(function () {
            var day = $(this).find(".day").text();

            if (day > 6) {
                $(this).find(".count").addClass('up');
            } else {
                $(this).find(".count").addClass('down');
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="new-container">
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <article>
                <div class="grid_wrap">
                    <div class="count">
                        <div class="inner"><span class="day">6</span><span class="txt">일</span> <span class="time">5</span> : <span class="minute">44</span> : <span class="second">31</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ctt">
                            <div class="date">2022. 01. 10</div>
                            <div class="tit">title</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add html to your post

Comment: what is .day ? is it a input text for normal text ? if it is input html element then you better use .val() instead of .text()

Comment: .day is normal text

Answer (score 0):

The `day` variable is a string. Use parseInt to turn it into an integer:

```
var day = parseInt($(this).find(".day").text()); // .val() if using HTML input, like what Onkar Manvelikar says
```